# Does GTM dataLayer.push affects performance?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-tag-manager

My question is about how `dataLayer.push(obj)` effects performance in `Angular SPA` application.

In SignUpComponent there is a method `showPopup()`

***SignUpComponent:***

```
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
    popupIsVisible: boolean = false;

    constructor() {}

    showPopup() {
        window['dataLayer'].push({
             RegistrationType: 'RMG',
             event: 'OpenRegPopup',
        });
        this.popupIsVisible = true;
    }
}
```

The thing is when I call `window['dataLayer'].push` before `this.popupIsVisible = true`, animation when popup is showing is a little-bit laggy and choppy, but if I remove `window['dataLayer'].push` animation is clear and smooth.

I have added `javascripts` for google tag manager in the `index.html` like their docs are saying [link1](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart) [link2](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide).

I have no idea what causes this choppy animations when calling `window['dataLayer'].push`, is there something that I may have missed? or any possible solutions?

Is it a good practice for example if I call `window['dataLayer'].push` asynchronously, or maybe calling them from web workers?

Comment: `window.dataLayer.push` is just pushing into an array (that's all `window.dataLayer` is) but depending on what else is going on in GTM with tags and triggers, it could affect performance. I've seen people do some very strange and bad things in GTM. It wouldn't hurt to wrap it in a function (which should also check if window.dataLayer exists, because of ad blockers), but if you're seeing performance problems I would start with auditing tags and triggers in GTM.